# libGDX Execution failed for task ':html:draftCompileGwt'

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I'm new to libGDX, I created an empty project for desktop and HTML. No problem when I'm running desktop but when I'm running HTML with `./gradlew html:superDev`

> Console error

```
Task :html:draftCompileGwt FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.gwt.util.regexfilter.RegexFilter: method <init>()V not found
    at com.google.gwt.util.regexfilter.WhitelistRegexFilter.<init> 
(WhitelistRegexFilter.java:21)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JJSOptionsImpl.<init> 
(JJSOptionsImpl.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompileTaskOptionsImpl.<init> 
(PrecompileTaskOptionsImpl.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilerOptionsImpl.<init> 
(CompilerOptionsImpl.java:30)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:108)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:draftCompileGwt'.
Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

---

> build.gradle (html)

```
gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.8.2' // Should match the gwt version used for building the gwt backend
    maxHeapSize="1G" // Default 256m is not enough for gwt compiler. GWT is HUNGRY
    minHeapSize="1G"

    src = files(file("src/")) // Needs to be in front of "modules" below.
    modules 'com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinition'
    devModules 'com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinitionSuperdev'
    project.webAppDirName = 'webapp'

    compiler {
        strict = true;
        disableCastChecking = true;
    }
}

import org.wisepersist.gradle.plugins.gwt.GwtSuperDev

def HttpFileServer server = null
def httpFilePort = 8080

task startHttpServer () {
    dependsOn draftCompileGwt

    String output = project.buildDir.path + "/gwt/draftOut"

    doLast {
        copy {
            from "webapp"
            into output
        }

        copy {
            from "war"
            into output
        }

        server = new SimpleHttpFileServerFactory().start(new File(output), httpFilePort)

        println "Server started in directory " + server.getContentRoot() + ", http://localhost:" + server.getPort()
    }
}

task superDev (type: GwtSuperDev) {
    dependsOn startHttpServer
    doFirst {
        gwt.modules = gwt.devModules
    }
}


task dist(dependsOn: [clean, compileGwt]) {
    doLast {
        file("build/dist").mkdirs()
        copy {
            from "build/gwt/out"
            into "build/dist"
        }
        copy {
            from "webapp"
            into "build/dist"
            }
        copy {
            from "war"
            into "build/dist"
        }
    }
}

task addSource {
    doLast {
        sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += files(project(':core').sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
    }
}

tasks.compileGwt.dependsOn(addSource)
tasks.draftCompileGwt.dependsOn(addSource)

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-html"
}
```

---

I did not add any code, this is the project created by libGDX

> Ubuntu 19.04
>
> Java version : 12.0.1
>
> Gradle version : 5.4.1
>
> Gradlew version: 5.4.1

If you have an idea of the problem I take it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. The origin was my java version

> Old java version `java -version`

```
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12-Ubuntu-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So I have to change version, command to do it

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

In my case here is the result

```
  Sélection   Chemin                                          Priorité  État
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1211      mode automatique
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      mode manuel
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1211      mode manuel
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      mode manuel
```

I switched to version 8, for do this 2 solutions this command

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set "/path/java/..."
```

or with this command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` you can directly select the version

> Current java version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.19.04.2-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

And it's work fine